# pyspark : How to write dataframe partition by year/month/day/hour sub-directory?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have tab delimited data(csv file) like below:

```
201911240130 a
201911250132 b
201911250143 c
201911250223 z
201911250224 d
...
```

I want to write directory group by year, month, day, hour.

```
hdfs://dest/2019/11/24/01/xxxx.csv
hdfs://dest/2019/11/25/01/xxxx.csv
hdfs://dest/2019/11/25/02/xxxx.csv
```

How can I write partition by yyyy/mm/dd/hh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping column and filtering Dataframe is helpful for you.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sc = SparkSession.builder.appName("write_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_sample").getOrCreate()
df = sc.read.csv('hdfs://sample.csv', header=False, sep="\t");

partition_column = '_c0' # First column

# Extracts parts of a string(yyyymmddhh)
dir_yyyymmddhh = df[partition_column][1:10]

# Get unique yyyymmddhh values in the grouping column
groups = [x[0] for x in df.select(dir_yyyymmddhh).distinct().collect()]

# Create a filtered DataFrame
groups_list = [df.filter(F.col(partition_column)[1:10] == x) for x in groups]

# Save the result by yyyy/mm/dd/hh
for filtered_data in groups_list:
    target_date = filtered_data.select(partition_column).take(1)[0].asDict()[partition_column]
    # Extract each directory name
    dir_year = target_date[0:4]
    dir_month = target_date[4:6]
    dir_day = target_date[6:8]
    dir_hour = target_date[8:10]
    # Set destination directory by yyyy/mm/dd/hh
    partitioned_directory = 'hdfs://dest/' + dir_year +'/'+ str(dir_day) +'/'+ str(dir_hour) +'/'
    filtered_data.write.option("header", "false").option("sep","\t").csv(partitioned_directory)
```

Result:

```
hdfs://dest/2019/11/24/01/part-0000-xxxx.csv
hdfs://dest/2019/11/25/01/part-0000-xxxx.csv
hdfs://dest/2019/11/25/02/part-0000-xxxx.csv
```

Answer (score 7):

There is already `partitionBy` in DataFrameWriter which does exactly what you need and it's much simpler. Also, there are functions to extract date parts from timestamp.

Here is another solution you can consider.

As your CSV does not have a header your can apply a custom header when you load it, this way it is easy to manipulate columns later:

```
custom_header = "timestamp\tvalue"
schema = StructType()
col_names = custom_header.split("\t")
for c in col_names:
    schema.add(StructField(c.strip(), StringType()))

df = spark.read.csv("hdfs://sample.csv", header=False, sep="\t", schema=schema)
```

Now, create the columns `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour` from the column `timestamp` as follows:

```
df_final = df.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp(col("timestamp"), 'yyyyMMddHHmm')) \
           .withColumn("year", date_format(col("timestamp"), "yyyy")) \
           .withColumn("month", date_format(col("timestamp"), "MM")) \
           .withColumn("day", date_format(col("timestamp"), "dd")) \
           .withColumn("hour", date_format(col("timestamp"), "HH")) \
           .drop("timestamp")

df_final.show(truncate=False)

+-----+----+-----+---+----+
|value|year|month|day|hour|
+-----+----+-----+---+----+
|a    |2019|11   |24 |01  |
|b    |2019|11   |25 |01  |
|c    |2019|11   |25 |01  |
|z    |2019|11   |25 |02  |
|d    |2019|11   |25 |02  |
+-----+----+-----+---+----+
```

Finally, write DF to destination path using `partitionBy` like this:

```
df_final.write.partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .option("header", "false").option("sep", "\t") \
    .csv("hdfs://dest/")
```

Partitions will be created under `/dest/` folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But your code has different results.
`hdfs://dest/year=2019/month=11/day=24/hour=01/part-0000-xxx.csv`

Comment: @AndersonChoi That's how spark understands partitions. With your solution, if you need to read back the data there are no benefits as you just created subfolders and not partitions. You can find more details [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery).

Comment: Thank you for your kindness and the explanation. Nevertheless, I have to make partition like _yyyy/mm/dd/hh_ because such format is the most appropriate format for our service.

Comment: If you're doing this because you want to subset queries by month, year, day, it would be much better to just partition by date.